# how do I replace this html using regex

Tags: asp.net, regex, replace

I'm kinda new to regex and if you can help me understand how I can replace
the escaped chars back to literal html string using regex , I would really appreciate it.
I tried using string.replace and it only replaced certain portion of the code not all.

ex: `string.replace("&lt;","<") ;` //this works but only on one line, when it becomes a loop it's a problem, and for those who are familiar with the code, yes this is a SP blog code where SP converts the html literal tag to escaped chars.

```
<div class="ExternalClass2BF55814E98A409296EC90A2605D7D74">
  <div>&ltiframe src=&quot
    <a href=http://player.vimeo.com/video/32001208?portrait=0&ampampbadge=0>
            http://player.vimeo.com/video/32001208?portrait=0&ampampbadge=0
    </a>&quot;
    width=&quot;420&quot; height=&quot;281&quot; frameborder=&quot0&quot 
    webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen&gt&lt/iframe&gt; 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: String.Replace() in .NET replaces ALL instances. Concat the lines together and replace it in bulk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your string is encoded HTML you may be better to run it through `Server.HtmlDecode()`. this will convert it back to HTML.

I.E

```
    '' In VB
    Dim myHtml as String = Server.HtmlDecode(YourConcatonatedEncodedHTML)

    // in C#
    string myHtml = Server.HtmlDecode(YourConcatonatedEncodedHTML);
```